# Spring Autowire cannot find implementation for R2DBC Repository in Generic Class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-r2dbc

```java
@Service
public abstract class BaseService<R extends IChanakyaR2dbcRepository<E, String>, E, D> {

    @Autowired
    protected R repository;

    public abstract D convertToDTO(E entity);

    public abstract E convertToEntity(D DTO);

    public Flux<D> findAll() {
        return repository.findAll().map(this::convertToDTO);
    }

    public Mono<D> findById(String id) {
        return repository.findById(id).map(this::convertToDTO);
    }

    public Mono<D> create(D DTO) {
        return repository.insert(convertToEntity(DTO)).map(this::convertToDTO);
    }

    public Mono<D> update(D DTO) {
        return repository.save(convertToEntity(DTO)).map(this::convertToDTO);
    }

    public Mono<Void> delete(D DTO) {
        return repository.delete(convertToEntity(DTO));
    }
}
```

I have the above class as an abstract class from which all my base services class will inherit.

```java
@Service
public class ClusterService extends BaseService<IChanakyaR2dbcRepository<ClusterEntity, String>, ClusterEntity, ClusterDTO> {

    @Autowired
    ModelMapper modelMapper;

    @Override
    public ClusterDTO convertToDTO(ClusterEntity entity) {
        return modelMapper.map(entity, ClusterDTO.class);
    }

    @Override
    public ClusterEntity convertToEntity(ClusterDTO DTO) {
        return modelMapper.map(DTO, ClusterEntity.class);
    }

}
```

This is my service class.

```java
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface IChanakyaR2dbcRepository<T, ID> extends ReactiveCrudRepository<T, ID> {

    /**
     * Inserts a given entity. Use the returned instance for further operations as the save operation might have changed the
     * entity instance completely.
     *
     * @param entity must not be {@literal null}.
     * @return {@link Mono} emitting the inserted entity.
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException in case the given {@literal entity} is {@literal null}.
     */
    <S extends T> Mono<S> insert(S entity);

}
```

This is my repository class.

```java
@Slf4j
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class ChanakyaR2dbcRepository<T, ID> extends SimpleR2dbcRepository<T, ID> {

    private final RelationalEntityInformation<T, ID> entity;
    private final DatabaseClient databaseClient;
    private final R2dbcConverter converter;
    private final ReactiveDataAccessStrategy accessStrategy;

    public ChanakyaR2dbcRepository(RelationalEntityInformation entity, DatabaseClient databaseClient, R2dbcConverter converter, ReactiveDataAccessStrategy accessStrategy) {
        super(entity, databaseClient, converter, accessStrategy);
        this.entity = entity;
        this.databaseClient = databaseClient;
        this.converter = converter;
        this.accessStrategy = accessStrategy;
    }

    @Transactional
    public <S extends T> Mono<S> insert(S objectToSave) {

        Assert.notNull(objectToSave, "Object to insert must not be null!");

        try {
            return this.databaseClient.insert()
                    .into(this.entity.getJavaType())
                    .table(this.entity.getTableName()).using(objectToSave)
                    .map(this.converter.populateIdIfNecessary(objectToSave))
                    .first()
                    .defaultIfEmpty(objectToSave);
        } catch(DataIntegrityViolationException diex) {
            String errMsg = String.format("Entity {} already exists in database", this.entity);
            log.error(errMsg, diex);
            return Mono.error(new IllegalStateException(errMsg));
        }
    }

}
```

This is my repository implementation.

When I run the application it, I get the following error.

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'clusterService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repository';
>   nested exception is
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   'com.appdynamics.sum.chanakya.repository.base.IChanakyaR2dbcRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies
>   as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

The above autowire doesn't work, but when I autowire `IChanakyaR2dbcRepository<ClusterEntity, String>` in another componenet directly ( not via a generic type ). It works fine.

What is the correct way to do such a thing? I want to have BaseService implementation.

I know if you create an interface that extends `IChanakyaR2dbcRepository<ClusterEntity, String>` and pass that class as the generic type to `BaseService` then it will work fine. But that would mean creating such empty classes for every entity I have which is not an ideal solution.

Answer (score 2):

you should try this :

```
@EnableR2dbcRepositories(basePackages = {"your.repository.package"}, 
basePackageClasses = {})
```

the problem lies in the fact springboot does not know where to find this custom type `r2dbc` repository

Comment: you do not need to declare an implementation to interface itself, unless you absolutely want to customize something beyond crud

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite sure what you are trying to achieve.
If you want your IChanakyaR2dbcRepository to be a "baserepository" (hence @NoRepositoryBean) and have "another" @Repository extend it and autowire it in your  "Base Service"

```
@Repository
MyIChanakyaR2dbcRepository ....

@Autowire
MyIChanakyaR2dbcRepository rep;
```

or autowire an @Repository in your ClusterService
or your "BaseService" should **implement** any of your Repositories (depends on what you are trying to achieve)

but just telling from the exception you need to provide an @Repository in your "BaseService" as in

```
@Repository
MyIChanakyaR2dbcRepository extends "YourBasyRepository"<"YourEntityType", "YourIdType">{.....}

@Service
public abstract class BaseService<R extends IChanakyaR2dbcRepository<E, String>, E, D> {

    @Autowired
    protected MyIChanakyaR2dbcRepository repository;
```

you can't autowire @NoRepositoryBeans